# Logging into a linux box using a different id

Tags: linux, unix

I have a basic question,am logging to a linux box using securecrt with my username and password,it has my username and password saved,i want to login using a different username to the same linux box,how do I do that?since I am already logging and the data is saved,everytime I login its automatically logging with current credentials

Comment: Actually I am confused with your question. you want to login as a multiple user or you want to access the same account with two different user name ? can you be more specified?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **su**  **username**  - assuming you have the username setup. For more info on su, you can use `man su` on command prompt which will give you all the details.

```
NAME
       su - change user ID or become superuser

SYNOPSIS
       su [options] [username]

DESCRIPTION
       The su command is used to become another user during a login session. 
       Invoked without a username, su defaults to becoming the superuser. The
       optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to 
       what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work for you, try this

First create 2 users `user1` and `user2`

```
[root@localhost ~]# useradd user1
[root@localhost ~]# passwd user1
Changing password for user user1.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: it is too short
BAD PASSWORD: is too simple
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@localhost ~]# useradd user2
[root@localhost ~]# passwd user2
Changing password for user user2.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: it is too short
BAD PASSWORD: is too simple
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

In `/etc/passwd` file change this

```
user1:x:502:502::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:503:503::/home/user2:/bin/bash
```

To This

```
user1:x:502:502::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:502:502::/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

Now If you login from user2 then user1 home directory will open.
Note

Here passwd for user1 is user1 and for user2 is user2